# Run code in python script on shutdown signal

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, shutdown

I have a python script that runs in the background on startup. The starting method is a entry in a run.sh file which is called with /etc/rc.local. The exact entry would be "sudo python /home/pi/run/main.py &". The system is a raspberry pi with wheezy.

The script is running, no problem so far. If a shutdown command is send to the system (via console "sudo shutdown -h now") I need further the script to not abort right away but to execute some code first. Thats what I got so far:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import atexit

@atexit.register
def byebye():
    c = "End"
    datei = open("/home/pi/logfile",'a+b')
    datei.write(c + "\n")
    datei.close()

def main():

   while True:
     ...do anything...

main()
```

Right now it seems to just exit the main loop on shutdown. Do I need to use a different way to shutdown the system so the signal is transmitted to my script or did I maybe not get the usage of the "@atexit" method? Any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: Maybe if you look at how molly-guard - http://packages.debian.org/sid/all/molly-guard/filelist - does it, you will have a better method?

Comment: Thanks for your comment but it seems this code is way above my expertise...don´t even know how to begin there... :(

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`shutdown` sends the `SIGTERM` signal, which `atexit` does not handle.  Nor will context managers, `finally` blocks, etc.

```
import signal

signal.getsignal(signal.SIGTERM)
Out[64]: 0 #i.e. nothing
```

Contrast this with, say ctrl-C:

```
signal.getsignal(signal.SIGINT)
Out[65]: <function signal.default_int_handler> #i.e. something
```

You can register your `byebye` function with `signal` to run instead of doing nothing (which leads to the interpreter eventually getting killed by the shell)

```
signal.signal(signal.SIGTERM,byebye)
```

If you do the above you'll need to do two things:

- change the signature of `byebye` to accept the two arguments that `signal` will pass to it.
- you should do something like call `sys.exit()` at the end of your `byebye` function to allow python to gracefully close up shop.

You could alternatively do some combination of `signal` *and* `atexit`:

```
import sys
signal.signal(signal.SIGTERM, lambda num, frame: sys.exit(0))
```

Which would drop right in to your current code.  This ensures the atomicity of your cleanup operation (i.e. `byebye` is guaranteed to be the last I/O operation) at the cost of being a bit clunky.

Comment: +1 for the lambda.  I don't think it's clunky, provided it's commented.

Comment: Yeah that's my only concern - your code doesn't declare where/what your exit handler is anymore.  It could be modules, nay, *packages* away!  (so yeah, use a comment :-))

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer...that was the push i needed! :-)