# Gracefully End Python Program

Tags: python, python-3.x, debian

How do I write to logs, close files etc. when my python program gets killed by a system shutdown?  The program is a long running process which uses a while True loop i.e.

```
while True:
    # Open files
    #do long running process
```

If the system is shutdown while this is running, can it get a signal so that it knows to cleanup e.g. close files, write "shutting down..." to log etc.  What would the code look like to handle this?

Code is Python 3 running on Debian Wheezy.  Program will be started by an init script on system start up.

Thanks.

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21613710/run-code-in-python-script-on-shutdown-signal.

Comment: look up context managers and the 'with' statement.

Comment: Here's the [clean-up code section in the official docs](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/errors.html#defining-clean-up-actions) discussing the try: finally: syntax and the with...: context manager.  This should put you on the right track.

Comment: You need to handle the shutdown signal.  See the answer in laike9m's link.