# Trapping a shutdown event in Python

Tags: python-2.7, raspberry-pi, shutdown

I posted a question about how to catch a "sudo shutdown -r 2" event in Python.  I was sent to this thread: [Run code in python script on shutdown signal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21613710/run-code-in-python-script-on-shutdown-signal) .

I'm running a Raspberry Pi v2 with Jessy.

I have read about

> signal

and have tried to follow the ideas in the above thread, but so far I have not been successful.  Here is my code:

```
import time
import signal
import sys
def CloseAll(Code, Frame):
    f = open('/mnt/usbdrive/output/TestSignal.txt','a')
    f.write('Signal Code:' + Code)
    f.write('Signal Frame:' + Frame)
    f.write('\r\n')
    f.close()
    sys.exit(0)

signal.signal(signal.SIGTERM,CloseAll)
print('Program is running')
try:
  while True:
#get readings from sensors every 15 seconds 
    time.sleep(15)

    f = open('/mnt/usbdrive/output/TestSignal.txt','a')
    f.write('Hello ')
    f.write('\r\n')
    f.close()

except KeyboardInterrupt:
     f = open('/mnt/usbdrive/output/TestSignal.txt','a')
     f.write('Done')
     f.write('\r\n')
     f.close()
```

The program runs in a "screen" session/window and reacts as expected to a CNTL-C.  However, when I exit the screen session, leaving the program running, and enter "sudo shutdown -r 2", the Pi reboots as expected after 2 minutes, but the TestSignal.txt file does not show that the signal.SIGTERM event was processed.

What am I doing wrong?  Or better yet, how can I trap the shutdown event, usually initiated by a cron job, and close my Python program running in a screen session gracefully?

Comment: Are you sure the media is still mounted when the handler executes?

Comment: @RDK please check my answer (it works on my system) but try to also be quite atomic in the `CloseAll` function body and have an eye on the availability of the mount point during shutdown as http://stackoverflow.com/users/20862/ignacio-vazquez-abrams indicated above.

Answer (score 1):

When you do not try to await such an event, but in a parallel session send `SIGTERM`to that process (e.g. by calling `kill -15 $PID` on the process id `$PID` of the python script running) , you should see an instructive error message ;-)

Also the comment about the mount point should be of interest after you repaired the python errors (`TypeError: cannot concatenate 'str' and 'int' objects`).

Try something like:

```
import time
import signal
import sys

LOG_PATH = '/mnt/usbdrive/output/TestSignal.txt'


def CloseAll(Code, Frame):
    f = open(LOG_PATH, 'a')
    f.write('Signal Code:' + str(Code) + ' ')
    f.write('Signal Frame:' + str(Frame))
    f.write('\r\n')
    f.close()
    sys.exit(0)

signal.signal(signal.SIGTERM, CloseAll)
print('Program is running')
try:
    while True:
        # get readings from sensors every 15 seconds
        time.sleep(15)

        f = open(LOG_PATH, 'a')
        f.write('Hello ')
        f.write('\r\n')
        f.close()

except KeyboardInterrupt:
    f = open(LOG_PATH, 'a')
    f.write('Done')
    f.write('\r\n')
    f.close()
```

as a starting point. If this works somehow on your system why not rewrite some portions like:

```
# ... 8< - - -
def close_all(signum, frame):
    with open(LOG_PATH, 'a') as f:
        f.write('Signal Code:%d Signal Frame:%s\r\n' % (signum, frame))
    sys.exit(0)

signal.signal(signal.SIGTERM, close_all)
# 8< - - - ...
```

**Edit**: To further isolate the error and adapt more to production like mode, one might rewrite the code like this (given that syslog is running on the machine, which it should, but I never worked on devices of that kind):

```
#! /usr/bin/env python
import datetime as dt
import time
import signal
import sys
import syslog

LOG_PATH = 'foobarbaz.log'  # '/mnt/usbdrive/output/TestSignal.txt'


def close_all(signum, frame):
    """Log to system log. Do not spend too much time after receipt of TERM."""
    syslog.syslog(syslog.LOG_CRIT, 'Signal Number:%d {%s}' % (signum, frame))
    sys.exit(0)

# register handler for SIGTERM(15) signal
signal.signal(signal.SIGTERM, close_all)


def get_sensor_readings_every(seconds):
    """Mock for sensor readings every seconds seconds."""
    time.sleep(seconds)
    return dt.datetime.now()


def main():
    """Main loop - maybe check usage patterns for file resources."""
    syslog.syslog(syslog.LOG_USER, 'Program %s is running' % (__file__,))
    try:
        with open(LOG_PATH, 'a') as f:
            while True:
                f.write('Hello at %s\r\n' % (
                    get_sensor_readings_every(15),))
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        with open(LOG_PATH, 'a') as f:
            f.write('Done at %s\r\n' % (dt.datetime.now(),))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    sys.exit(main())
```

Points to note:

1. the log file for the actual measurements is separate from the logging channel for operational alerts
2. the log file handle is safeguarded in context managing blocks and in usual operation is just kept open
3. for alerting the `syslog` channel is used.
4. as a sample for the message routing the `syslog.LOG_USER` on my system (OS X) gives me in all terminals a message, whilst the `syslog.LOG_ERR` priority message in signal handler only targets the system log.
5. should be more to the point during shutdown hassle (not opening a file, etc.)

The last point (5.) is important in case all processes receive a `SIGTERM` during shutdown, i.e. all want to do something (slowing things down), maybe `screen`also does not accept any buffered input anymore (or does not flush), note `stdout` is block buffered not line buffered.

The decoupling of the output channels, should also ease the eventual disappearance of the mount point of the measurement log file.

Comment: OK, I have made the changes to my program, as you suggested.  However, I'm not sure I understand your very first comments about "waiting for an event in a parallel session.

Comment: OK, I have made the changes to my program.  However, I'm not sure I understand your very first comments about "waiting for an event in a parallel session".  Regardless, I still can not seem to get this to work, independent of the location of the log file. I suspect it does have something to do with the fact that the "sudo shutdown -r 2" is issued in the main console window while the Python program is running in a "screen" window?  If I get this to work a cron job will initiate the "shutdown -r 2" command about once a week.

Comment: Ah ok, sorry. What about this: For testing you can simulate the signal received during shitdown with the unix command 'kill'. Without tha complication, that during shutdown all services will be halted and error messages may be hidden. Those you van observr in a relaxed mode when sending the signal in isolation. HTH

Comment: Also, I returned to the "Screen" window after issuing the "sudo shutdown -r 2" command, so I could watch the program to see if any message/error were displayed.  Nothing.

Comment: Actually, no, as I added a print statement to the CloseAll function so I might see that it was being called.  I saw no output from the pgm

Comment: Using the "kill -15 ..."  command, issued from the main console window, I do see the print output from the CloseAll function when I return to the "screen" window. So that part is working.  But I do not see this when I issue the "shutdown -r 2" command.

Comment: Thanks for the programming lesson, I'll study it and try to understand what you did.  However, even with the addition of the syslog I'm not seeing any messages affecting my program during the reboot.  No happiness here.  Perhaps the Raspberry Pi with Raspbian/Jessy is too different from your OSx?  Thanks for trying.

Comment: You're welcome. When you issue this shutdown command, does it display something like sending term signal to all processes in that console? This should be a debia. Like distribution, right?

Comment: From the main console window this is what I see after issuing the shutdown -r 2 command:
**Broadcast message from root@xxxxx (Tue 2016-05-31 15:52:50 CEST):
The system is going down for reboot at Tue 2016-05-31 15:54:50 CEST!**

I think the Raspbian Jessie is a Debian distribution for the Raspberry Pi?

Comment: Thanks for the info. I will have to look that up myself ... I remember from ubuntu nice detailed messages when issuing reboot command that exactly state the signals being sent ...